# Extends constructors from a class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, jlist

I have a class that extends JList and I don't know how to make the JList constructors work in my class. I know that this can be made with JList constructor:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);
```

Instead, if I do the same with my class:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
DatabaseJList lista = new DatabaseJList(model);
```

The IDE suggest me to remove argument to match DatabaseJList.

Aren't supposed to be Jlist constructors inherited to my class when I extend it?

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 4):

No. You must define constructors explicitly. Any constructor that you want to "inherit" must be defined in the subclass, and most likely has to call `super(..)` with the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not inherited (at least, not in the sense that you're thinking of).  You must explicitly write such a constructor:

```
class DatabaseJList extends JList {

    public DatabaseJList(ListModel model) {
        super(model);  // Call through to the super-class constructor
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: You should user the interface `ListModel` instead of the class `DefaultListModel` (ie, program to the interface).

Comment: @Steve: Ah, I didn't consider that `ListModel` might be a thing.  I will update...

Answer (score 0):

You can call the superclass's constructor in your class's constructor using

```
super(...)
```

Define a constructor in your class with the same parameters as the super classes'. Then simply use super() to call the superclass constructor and then continue to do your initializations

*Remember, super() should be on the first line of your constructor*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put super(model); in your DatabaseJList constructor